# when I receive an SMS from the user, send automated sms

Tags: twilio

In twilio, I want to send automated sms like “Thanks for contacting us, we will reply to you shortly” to the user when I receive an SMS from the user.

Please let me know how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio.

Have you checked out the documentation on http://twilio.com? There is a good tutorial on starting with messaging in the quickstart section on [sending and receiving messages with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/sms). There are instructions in PHP, Python, Ruby, Java and C# that should be able to get you going.

Let me know if this helps.